How to add row number to simple GROUP BY query?
I've looked at other questions but they don't seem to handle this situation.
I want to run a simple COUNT and GROUP BY on a single column in a table:
select name as Name, 
       count(name) as Frequency 
from table 
group by Name 
order by Frequency desc;

This shows a ton of results, but I want to know the ranking of each row.
So, instead of this:
Name | Frequency
John | 27,001
Mary | 26,845
Joe  | 26,550
...

I want this:
Rank | Name | Frequency
1    | John | 27,001
2    | Mary | 26,845
3    | Joe  | 26,550
...

I've tried using ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Rank but the numbers seems to be random.
Thank you.

You have to do the aggregation in a derived-table subquery, then do the row numbering window function in the outer query:
select 
  row_number() over (order by Frequency desc) AS `rank`,
  name,
  Frequency
from (
  select name as Name,
         count(name) as Frequency
  from mytable
  group by Name
) as t
order by Frequency desc;

You may do the order by Frequency desc either in the subquery or in the outer query.

Thank. Unfortunately the ranking goes random every now and then. For example,
662147 | Amar |         1 ,
646935 | Moffy |         1 . Notice the ranking went from 662147 -> 646935

@MadjeKolak that's probably a result of how rank function handles ties. You may need to look into dense_rank and decide which one you want to use.
